# C++/CLI Winforms User Control Property, Nested Category Attribute

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, custom-controls

I'm building a user control. Below is an example of one of it's properties. I would like this property to be located within a couple nested categories.

```
public:
    [Description("Text to display as Rick's Age"), Category("Tiny Rick")]
    property String^ Rick_Age
    {
        String^ get()
        {
            return RicksAge_Label->Text;
        }
        void set(String^ newText)
        {
            RicksAge_Label->Text = newText;
        }
    }
```

For this example the `Variable_Text` property is located in the `Tiny Rick` category. How can I make the `Tiny Rick` category appear within another category?

I'd like to have some kind of multiple tiered organization of properties. For example:

- Category: `Special Properties`

  - Category: `Tiny Rick`

    - Property: `Rick_Age`
  - Category: `Morty`

    - Property: `Morty_Age`
    - Property: `Morty_Size`
- Category: `Other Properties`

  - Category: `Jerry`

    - Property: `Jerry_Age`
    - Property: `Jerry_Employed`
  - Category: `Courier Flaps`

    - Property: `Item_to_Ship`

EDIT-1:
Here is an example of nested properties. It is the property panel for a newly placed button control (not a custom user control). I understand that this doesn't prove the ability to apply a similar feature in a user control. It is simply a good illustration of what I'm trying to accomplish. The pictures denote the progression of accessing the `X` property:

[image: collapsed]

[image: Open1]

[image: Open2]

[image: Open3]

EDIT-2:
Considering what all can be done with user controls and custom design time properties (see [this project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10558/Shape-Control-for-NET)), I'm inclined to believe my goal is obtainable. This picture is from the previous link:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that control properties support the concept of nested categories. Before asking "how do I do this?", are you sure it's possible? Do you have an example of it being done with some other control, user or otherwise?

Comment: @DavidYaw Great question. I have updated my question to reflect my response.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible.

Looking through the [.Net Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/1160e329ef416b2d.html) at all places where the `CategoryAttribute` class is instantiated (in other words, all times that `Category` is used as an attribute on some property (scroll down to "422 instantiations of CategoryAttribute" in the lefthand pane)):

- There's no instances of multiple `Category` attributes on a single property (which is disallowed for the `CategoryAttribute` anyway).
- There's no categories with a hierarchy in their category text (e.g., there's no `[Category("Special Properties\\Morty")]`).

I think you're out of luck.